# mining of sh256 coins

Tags: bitcoin-core

I'm new in mining 
I just bought one s9 miner, 
Want to know that how can i mine any sh256 coin with s9 miner ?
I was searching about it and different pools, 
but everywhere they said like this

---

1. Create account.

Register here, or login if you already have account
Create a worker that will be used by the miner to login
2. Download a miner.

Intel/ATI/AMD CGMiner: Download here
Intel/ATI/AMD BFGMiner Linux/Windows: Download here
Fabulous Panda Miner Mac OS X: Download here
Minerd CPU Miner Mac/Linux/Windows: Download here.
3. Configure your miner.

Settings for Stratum:

STRATUM:    stratum+tcp://mine1.mpool.me
PORT (Low hash rates):  4012 (varDiff: 16 - 4096, initial diff: 128)
PORT (High hash rates): 4112 (varDiff: 2048 - 65535, initial diff: 2048)
Username:   Weblogin.Worker
Password:   Worker Password

If your using Linux, Then type the following into the console:

---

please help me how to configure miner

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have previously reviewed the steps for configuring the Antminer S9.

You need to register an account with a pool and add a worker.

The stratum information is what you need to put into the Antminer S9 configuration.

You need to know the IP address of your S9 on the network. If you do not know it, use [Advanced IP Scanner](https://www.advanced-ip-scanner.com/) (or similar, I do not know if you are running Windows?) and find it.

Open `http://x.x.x.x/` (IP of your S9) in your web browser and login. In the Miner Configuration tab, enter your stratum information there.

```
URL: stratum+tcp://mine1.mpool.me:{PORT} - you have choices for PORT 4012/4112
Worker: {your worker name} - you should have configured this in the pool where it may be called Worker Username.
Password: {your worker password}
```

Save & Apply.

Your miner will  not start until it registers.

You may enjoy this video (the sound is quiet!):
[How to setup Antminer S9, R4 GUI- Set mining pools, ECT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QNek1wjUIF4)

Enjoy mining!